# What does a class followed by _t (underscore-t) in typename statement represent?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following block of code:

```
template<template<typename ...> class ProxyType_, template<typename> class AttributeExtension_>
struct DefaultAttributeProxyHelper;

template<template<typename ...> class ProxyClass_, template<typename> class AttributeExtension_>
std::shared_ptr<typename DefaultAttributeProxyHelper<ProxyClass_, AttributeExtension_>::class_t> 
createProxyWithDefaultAttributeExtension(const std::string &_domain, const std::string &_instance);
```

I am not able to understand what does class_t mean in the statement below and what does the statement finally implies

```
typename DefaultAttributeProxyHelper<ProxyClass_, AttributeExtension_>::class_t
```

Comment: It is a convention typically used to show that the name is a `typedef`. In this case, it probably refers to some class type that the `DefaultAttributeProxyHelper` handles in some way, that is dependant on the template arguments it is instantiated with. A bit like [`std::vector::value_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types). But you will have to look at the documentation for `DefaultAttributeProxyHelper`, whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a convention of naming data types with `typedef`. It comes from `C` language which don't have namespaces and thus must use such conventions to avoid name conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old C convention used to remember what a name is: _t for data types, _s for structs,  _e for enum, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Althrough it was asked five years ago, a short answer is given after checking the commonapi code. Hope it could help someone:
DefaultAttributeProxyHelper is declared in AttributeExtension.hpp of capicxx-core-runtime project. However, its definition is implemented in generated code using commonapi-core-generator. If E02Attributes example in capicxx-core-tools is fully executed, you would find the DefaultAttributeProxyHelper definition and its class_t definition in E02AttributesProxy.hpp

```
    template<template<typename > class _AttributeExtension>
    struct DefaultAttributeProxyHelper< ::v1::commonapi::E02AttributesProxy,
    _AttributeExtension> {
           typedef typename ::v1::commonapi::E02AttributesProxy<            ::v1::commonapi::E02AttributesExtensions::XAttributeExtension<_AttributeExtension>, 
 ::v1::commonapi::E02AttributesExtensions::A1AttributeExtension<_AttributeExtension>
> class_t;
};
```